# Use projection to create $A\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$ with $A\cdot A=A$ and $A\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

How to use

- Vector space $V = U \oplus W$
- Linear map $f: V \to V, x \mapsto \left \{ \begin{matrix} x ~~, & x \in U \\ 0 ~~, & x \in W \\ \end{matrix} \right. $
- $f = f \circ f$

to create

- Matrix $A \in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{Q})$
- $A \cdot A = A$
- $A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

?

Comment: So you want a $2x2$ matrix with rational entries that has $1$ as an eigenvalue this will be similar to one these matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\0&q
\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&q\end{bmatrix}$ where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

The condition $A\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ will force the similarity be to the matrix $\mathbb{I}_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @SebastianCor Not so. All that condition does is identify one of the eigenvectors of $1$. It says nothing about the other eigenvalue of $A$. Something similar to $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ is also a possibility. In fact, all but the two trivial projections (the identity map and zero map) are similar to this matrix.

Comment: @SebastianCor $A$ is _similar_ to $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&q\end{bmatrix}$, not identical to it. There’s an unknown change-of-basis matrix between it and the vector that you left out.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $f$ tells us that $U$ is its image and $W$ its kernel. Moreover, the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is the identity map. If we assume that both $U$ and $W$ are nontrivial, then with a suitable choice of basis the matrix of $f$ is $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$, i.e., $$A = B\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}B^{-1}$$ for some invertible matrix $B$.

The condition $A(1,1)^T=(1,1)^T$ tells us that $(1,1)^T\in U$. Taking that as the basis for $U$, $$B = \begin{bmatrix}1&*\\1&*\end{bmatrix}.$$ Now, since $V=U\oplus W$, choose any vector that’s not a multiple of $(1,1)^T$ to generate $\ker f$. That vector goes in place of the *s above. For an orthogonal projection, pick a vector orthogonal to $(1,1)^T$.

A similar argument can be made in terms of eigenvalues. The definition of $f$ tells us that the possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $0$, and that $(1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. $A$ is therefore either the identity matrix (trivial kernel) or similar to $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$. All that’s left is to choose a vector in the kernel of $f$.

If you allow $U$ or $W$ to be trivial, that opens up the possibilities $A=0$ and $A=I$. We can reject the first since we know of at least one vector that’s not mapped to $0$, but with $W=\{0\}$ we could have the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks :) However, I fail to see where you did use $f$. I'm not yet supposed to know about eigenvalues.

Comment: I used the properties of $f$ that you gave throughout the first paragraph. If you haven’t learned eigenvalues yet, you can make a similar argument in terms of the image and kernel of $f$: Its kernel is $W$ and when restricted to its image $U$, $f$ is the identity map. That means that with a suitable choice of basis, its matrix is $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$; apply a change of basis to get $A$. Finding a suitable basis follows the same reasoning as I gave for the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the dot product with an unit vector gives back the projection in the direction of that unit vector. This means that the mapping
$$x \mapsto e(e \cdot x)$$
Is the linear projection to $e$. If we write it out component-wise, we get that
$$x_i =\sum_j e_i (e_j x_j)=\sum_j e_i e_j x_j$$
We can notice that the $(i,j)$-th component of the projection matrix is $e_i e_j$.

In your case: $e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} [1,1]^t$, which means that $e_i e_j=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is one possible solution, but note that nothing in the question suggests that the projection must be orthogonal.

Comment: @amd You are right. But you already took care of the more general setting :)